# Resources For Implementing Custom UI Designs Into Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, user-interface

Being somewhat of a beginner to coding, I'm having trouble understanding how to code different custom UI designs into my application. I know that if I take a UI button into my storyboard, I can replace it with a custom image I added into my project from the identity inspector. Anything more than this? I'm clueless.

For example, if I had a custom login screen that had special designed text fields for the username and password, how would I hook up the code to that? Would I just add the screen into the storyboard like normal? Or if I had a custom designed collection view screen, how would I implement this in my project via Storyboard, as well as with code? Hope this makes sense. I'd love to get some screens designed, but want to make sure I know how to hook up everything correctly before doing so and requesting certain things.

I tried looking up different resources on the web for this, but cannot seem to find anything. Any help or guidance on the path to understanding how this works, is greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hey Deborah**

No one is perfect. But if you want, You can achieve, whatever you want----

Now come to the point-

If you want to create a label by code,

**Try this-**

```
 var label: UILabel = UILabel()
    label.frame = CGRectMake(50, 50, 200, 21)
    label.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    label.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    label.text = "test label"
    self.view.addSubview(label)
```

For whole things-

**Read it**

[Click here](http://www.apptuitions.com/programmatically-creating-uibuttonuilabeluitextfield-using-swift/)